# Are there redundancy in Feynman diagrams for a particular scattering, in terms of rotation of the diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

In the [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25haxRuZQUk&list=PLA2FDCCBC7956448F) (see after 00:11:40) Leonard Susskind discusses a particular instance of indication of redundancy in the Feynman diagrams of scattering of $\pi$ mesons via $\rho$ mesons.

[image]

He continues saying that if there is a Feynman diagram like that on the left, principles of QFT says that there is another one like that on the right. I suppose that what he is talking about is the different channels of the scattering, s-channel and t-channel. And he says, when people collected experimental data for the scattering, they found they seemed to overcount the diagrams, particularly the s-channel diagrams itself gives the experimentally observed value of the scattering. And in a later [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qllX-dkGfYI&list=PLA2FDCCBC7956448F&index=6)(see after 1:13:11) he argues that this fact is due to conformal symmetry of string action which leads to the Veneziano amplitude to take the form of beta function
$$\mathrm{B}(s, t)=\int_{0}^{1} z^{s-1}(1-z)^{t-1} d z$$
which is symmetric under exchange of $s$ and $t$.

My question: Are there redundancy in Feynman diagrams for a particular scattering, in terms of rotation of the diagram?